# Phaser 3 group incX is not a function

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Following the documentation https://phaser.io/phaser3/api/group
I've created a `group` and I tried to call the method `incX`

```
var group = this.add.group();
group.incX(10);
```

And I get `Uncaught TypeError: group.incX is not a function`
In fact, when I print the object into console:

```
console.log(group);
```

I don't see this method or other methods specified on the documentation.
Am I doing something wrong? Is the documentation outdated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As weird as it sounds, it seems that not all Phaser 3 information on phaser.io is up to date. You can grab the [current documentation on PhotonStorm's GitHub](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-docs) and browse it locally (just open any of the html files in the `docs` folder).

As for the code, assuming you expect that `.incX()` would increment the `x` property of each sprite in the group, here's a way to do it:

```
let children = group.getChildren();
children.forEach((child) => {
    if (child instanceof Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite) {
        child.x += 10;
    }
});
```